# Delete or Remove a line using Xlib library

Tags: c, linux, xlib

Assume that we draw a line in Xlib using the XDrawLine API, what is the best way to remove or delete the line?. Are there any dedicated API's for this or do we have to use a special implementation of the the same XDrawLine API?

Thanks in Advance for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a line the color of the background (e.g, white) over the top of another line to "erase" it, but there's no way to restore the original graphics that were there before you drew the first line — Xlib does not keep a history.

In general, though, your application should be able to do a full "repaint" of the window at any time (e.g, if the window is resized or minimized, or if it is "damaged" by another window crossing over it). What you're asking makes it sound like your application may not be able to do this right now, which will prevent it from working correctly in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to draw to off-screen pixmap and remember state (or pixmap copy) before you draw the line. Delete line == draw offline pixmap to that state ( or just copy saved pixmap back to screen )